# Sprintf causing segfault due to uninitialized values

Tags: c

I am new to C
this line of code seems to be causing a segfault based on debugging. valgrind says that there is something wrong with it calling upon uninitialized values. I assume it doesn't like how I made the Random integer to string stuff.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    printf("main now \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    

    if (argc >= 3)
    {
        printf("Too many files!\n");
    fflush(stdout);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    else{
    
        //Actual main part
        //Setting up random

        
        int choice2;   //user's choice
        int breaker = 1;

        printf("elsecheck \n");
        fflush(stdout);

        int randomnum = rand();

        //Convert random integer into a string
        char stringrandom[6] = {'0'};
        printf("2 \n");
        fflush(stdout);
        ////
        sprintf(randomnum, stringrandom, 10);
        fflush(stdout);
        //////
        printf("random \n");
        fflush(stdout); 
        
        //Onid for directory creation
        char onid[10] = "chankevi";

        //FD for file check
        int fd;
        //Strings for name of file
        char filename[1000];
        char* newFilePath;
```

Comment: the seg fault occours after the printf("2 \m") test statement in between the dividers just for clarity.

Comment: Please add your code to the question as text. What makes you think the first parameter to `sprintf` is an `int`?

Comment: Do you know how [`sprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) *works* ? Reading the documentation to learn the argument expectations, and ensuing behavior, of the functions you're calling may no only be informative, it may be problem-solving.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance I just had recently replaced my "itoa" to sprintf because i was told to use it as a replacement for my version. Is there a better alternative I should use

Comment: `sprintf` is fine as long as you use it correctly. Looking up some documentation would probably help: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: Note that if your compiler was not complaining about the call `sprintf(randomnum, stringrandom, 10);`. you either need to adjust the compilation options to add more warnings or you need to get a better compiler.

Answer (score -1):

In your code the usage of string printf `sprintf` is incorrect.

You probably want something like:

```
    sprintf(stringrandom,"%d", randomnum);
```

But actually you should not use `sprintf` at all since it is very prone to buffer overruns as there are no checks that the allocated buffer is long enough

https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf

Comment: Not my downvote, but `&stringrandom` is wrong.  So was the code in the question, but …